# Display an image from a file path in an image control

Tags: c#, image, xaml

I'm trying to do something that I though ought to be simple -- assign an image to an image control by using the file path.  Here is the xaml for the image control:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding FavPicPath, Converter={StaticResource Converter4}}" x:Name="imgSelected"
                   Width="600" Height="461"/>
```

Here's the converter:

```
public sealed class PathToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, string culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I suppose I am just too much in the dark to figure it out.  I know the path to the image is getting into FavPicPath as I can see it when debugging.  It is a path example       "C:\Users\John\Pictures\OldPictures\2010-04-18 18 Apr 2010 Mulberry flowers\18 Apr 2010 Mulberry flowers 022.JPG"

I have even tried putting that path directly in the image source of the control and still can't get it to show up.

I have tried many different ways to get the image to show up on the page to no avail.  Thanks for the help I consistently get from this forum.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747027(v=vs.110).aspx

This is not helping ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, mybirthname.  I had seen that bit before a I did go ahead and try it again.  Here is the xaml:                <Image Width="200">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="200"  
                            UriSource="{Binding FavPicPath, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>                                                 Again, I can see that FavPicPath variable has the correct path to the image file, but it still does not show up in the image control on the page.

Comment: Is this WPF or Silveirght app?

Comment: It's WPF, I guess.  It's for a Windows 8.1 Store App.  Just for reference of anyone who reads this issue, I gave up on using file path names in the database to handle pictures.  It's just too complex, too many protections on opening files.  I am forced to store the actual pictures in the database.